# Update React Native Screen when Firebase variable changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm new to firebase and don't know how to make a screen in my react native app update when a certain firebase variable changes.

In my app's homescreen,  a user's posts are fetched from firebase in `componentDidMount`, and then rendered:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setup();
};

setup = async () => {
  const { currentUser } = await firebase.auth();
  this.setState({ currentUser });

  await firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users/" + currentUser.uid + "/posts")
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      this.setState({posts: snapshot.val()})
    });
}

// render posts
```

In a separate screen, the user can choose to add a post and the firebase database is updated:

```
addPost = async () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  await firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users/" + currentUser.uid + "/posts")
    .push({
      post: // data for post
    });
```

However, though the database is successfully changed, the homescreen doesn't update and show the newly added post till it is manually reloaded. How do I add a listener to the homescreen, so that when the posts database variable changes, the screen automatically updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the same data between multiple screens, the best is to use Redux.

Using Redux, all your renders function (which needs a specific data from the store) will automatically refresh if a data is updated. That way, you can only handle one firebase listener to update your redux store.

I would create a "Post" reducer and dispatch an update action every time I got something new from the firebase listener.

```js
// Actions
const ADD = 'post/ADD';
const UPDATE = 'post/UPDATE';

// Initial state
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
};

// Reducer
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, action.post]
      };
    case UPDATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.posts
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Action Creators
export function addPost(post) {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    post
  };
}

export function updatePosts(posts) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE,
    posts
  };
}
```

And the listener would be like :

```js
import { update } from 'PostRedux.js'

firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users/" + currentUser.uid + "/posts")
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      Store.dispatch(update(snapshot.val()));
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this would be applicable for this app it wouldn't work if a different user logged onto the app on that device. However, could you tell me where you're supposed to add the listener code.

Comment: First, I would install redux-persist. Then, I would save your user data into a redux store (after a successful login, for example), so every time after the store is persisted, you can know if the user was previously logged or not. Then, only if the user is logged, you can call the listener. Don't forget to wipe the store every time the user is logging out.